# How do I refresh a page in Angular?

Tags: angular, user-interface, angular-material

How do I refresh a page in Angular after a click event, without reloading it?
I'm developing an ecommerce frontend in Angular material. I want that after the following click event on the button `Remove`, the page is refreshed in order to not see the element removed anymore. It's important for me that the page isn't reloaded, because if it were reloaded I would lose all the operations done before the click event.

```
<a mat-raised-button  routerLink="." color="accent" (click)="deleteProduct(productInCart.product.id, currentUser.id, productInCart.quantity, productInCart.product.price)" routerLink="/carts/cart_by_user"  routerLinkActive="active">Remove</a>
```

Comment: what do you mean "refresh"?

Comment: When I click on the button `Remove` I want to be redirected on the same page where I am at the moment of the click event, but I want that the object that I removed doesn't appear anymore. If I go to a different page and then I come back on the page where the click event appened, the object that I have removed isn't showed anymore and I  want that the same thing appens when I click on the `Remove` button whit the only difference that I don't want to change page but I want to remain on the same page. @LaurenceIninda

Comment: You need to maintain the 'state' of your model - if an item is to be shown/hidden on the UI, you need to have an indicator (either a calculation or a flag, for example) to use for showing/hiding.  If you go to a different page and back (via Angular routes, not browser navigating) you need to use that indicator. 

Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve this question. It needs more details before it can be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to refresh the page - your concern should instead be to change the data behind it and have Angular update the UI automatically, without refreshing the page, as a result.
My suggestion is to follow the Tour Of Heroes tutorial at https://angular.io/tutorial - it covers the scenario you describe and also introduces other Angular concepts you need to grasp.